# Select Pandas Columns by dtype and column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to keep numeric columns and specific column names. How do I do that?

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[68, 'DC', 'three', 'Sunny', 'Chance of Rain']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

In [12]: df.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
Out[12]:
   A
0  68
```

I want to create the following dataframe.

```
     A   D       E
0   68   Sunny   Chance of Rain
```

Comment: `concat` them..? or may be `df.select_dtypes('number').combine_first(df[['D','E']])`

Comment: `pd.merge(left=df.select_dtypes(include=['number']), right=df(columns=['A', 'D'...]), right_index=True, how='left')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would `union` column headers then use column filtering on the dataframe.

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.union(['D', 'E'])]
```

Output:

```
    A      D               E
0  68  Sunny  Chance of Rain
```

Answer (score 2):

First using `select_dtypes` then with `concat`

```
pd.concat([df.select_dtypes('number'),df[['C','D']]],axis=1)
Out[369]: 
    A      C      D
0  68  three  Sunny
```